How to avoid activation of insertMany() every time a server refreshes?
So I am trying to insert data in the database using Mongoose. Every time the server gets connected/refreshed .insertMany() runs thus inserting multiple copies of the same data in the database. I have tried to use MongoDB Playground to insert the data and then use Mongoose to fetch & send the data and it does solve the above problem but I want to use Mongoose only for insertion of the data.

Server.js

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const exchange_route = require('../routes/exchanges')
const data= require('../models/data')

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

async function connect_to_database() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/REST-2');
        console.log("Connected to database");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to connect to database:", error);
    }
}
connect_to_database(); 
data();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.use('/exchanges',exchange_route)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Data.js

const exchanges_2_documents = require('../models/schema')

async function feeding_exchange_2_documents(){
    try {
        await exchanges_2_documents.insertMany(
            [
    {
                  "id": "saucerswap-v2",
                  "name": "Saucerswap V2",
                  "year_established": null,
                  "country": null,
                  "description": "",
                  "url": "https://www.saucerswap.finance/swap",
                  "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/markets/images/1363/small/SAUCERSWAPv2_1.png?1706865384",
                  "has_trading_incentive": false,
                  "trust_score": 6,
                  "trust_score_rank": 100,
                  "trade_volume_24h_btc": 410.8171966697791,
                  "trade_volume_24h_btc_normalized": 410.8171966697791
                }
 ]
)
 } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

module.exports= feeding_exchange_2_documents


Please edit the question to clarify the problem — including a [mre]. I see a function data being invoked, but the code for it is missing — presumably it is responsible for the logic in the description text.

Could it be that the data() function inserts the data and that it runs everytime server.js runs, which is typically everytime the server gets restarted...?

@jsejcksn I have edited although the data.js file just inserts data to the db

It looks like you are trying to implement a concept known as Database Seeding where you insert an initial set of documents to your MongoDB collection.
However, because your server.js file runs every time your application starts-up, your run() function will also run every time your application starts-up. That means your feeding_exchange_2_documents() function is inserting documents every time. Clearly you want to avoid that.
Seeding is typically done on the command line when starting up your app for the first time or moving environments but a quick and simple approach you can take is to move the run() call into a route handler like so:
connect_to_database(); 
//data(); //< Delete it from here

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/seed', async (req, res) => {
   try{
      await data(); //< Add it in here
      res.send('Database Seeded');
   }catch(err){
      res.send('Error when seeding')
   }
});

Ideally you want to check if the documents you are seeding to the collection already exist so that you don't keep adding them so just check for "id": "saucerswap-v2" and throw an error if it's already in there like so:
async function feeding_exchange_2_documents(){
    try {
        const doc = await exchanges_2_documents.findOne({id: "saucerswap-v2"});
        if(!doc){ //< doc not found so free to insert
            await exchanges_2_documents.insertMany(
                [
                    {
                        "id": "saucerswap-v2",
                        "name": "Saucerswap V2",
                        "year_established": null,
                        "country": null,
                        "description": "",
                        "url": "https://www.saucerswap.finance/swap",
                        "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/markets/images/1363/small/SAUCERSWAPv2_1.png?1706865384",
                        "has_trading_incentive": false,
                        "trust_score": 6,
                        "trust_score_rank": 100,
                        "trade_volume_24h_btc": 410.8171966697791,
                        "trade_volume_24h_btc_normalized": 410.8171966697791
                    }
                ]
            )
        }else{
            // Doc was found so throw an error
            throw new Error('Database record already exists')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // Remember to throw the error again so that the route handler knows
        throw error;
    }
}

